# "Tickle Monster" vs. "Tickling Monster"

Tags: differences, nouns, adjectives

My small kids like tickling - we play a "Tickle Monster" game. I am wondering, is there any difference between word pairs like

- *tickle monster* vs. *tickling monster*
- *tickle machine* vs. *tickling machine*
- *race car* vs. *racing car*

used as a modifier to the noun? The possible usage, the meaning, or even one of them not allowed?

Comment: In English, most parts of speech can become other parts of speech just by using them that way. [Verbs and nouns are especially interchangeable](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/the-give-that-keeps-on-gifting-the-protean-nature-of-english-words-and-why-thats-a-good-thing/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tickle monster = a monster which|who tickles

Race car = a car to be used for racing

Tickle machine = a machine to be used for tickling

When the adjective formed from the bare infinitive modifies an object, the meaning of the adjective is "for the purpose of X". When the adjective modifies a being, the meaning of the adjective is "which|who does X".

Fry pan = a pan for frying

Fry cook = cook who fries food

Dance slippers = slippers for dancing

Dance partner = partner who dances

Normally, words ending in -ing  more often modify objects, and can mean "that which does X" or "that which gets X'd" or "that which produces the effect of X".

sewing machine  (a machine for sewing, the machine can sew)

punching bag (a bag for punching, the bag *gets* punched)

knitting needles (needles for knitting, the needles knit)

laughing gas (gas for laughing, gas that makes people laugh)

jumping beans (beans that jump)

Comment: Is this a real rule though? With the exception of 'fry cook' I would put '-ing' on your examples. Google search for 'fry pan meaning' redirects you to 'frying pan'.

Comment: In your question, I am not sure what "this" refers to. To this statement: *Normally, words ending in -ing more often modify objects* ?  I'm not setting up an across-the-board "rule" there that applies to all `-ing` adjectives. Clearly we can say "the running |singing | dancing | coughing | belching man". I was responding to notion of *purpose* that underlies the OP's question: machine *for* tickling,  car *for* racing.

Comment: @TRomano: so are *tickle monster* and *tickling monster" both valid, just each with a different meaning? Similarly for *race car* vs. *racing car* etc.

Comment: They can have different meanings or they can mean the same; it depends on context.  "Racing" can mean the same as "race" ("Little Johnny wants a racing car for his birthday" means the same as "Little Johnny wants a race car for his birthday") but with "The police were chasing the racing car" it is not a car that competes in races but a car that is going much faster than the speed limit. We also tend to say "He is a race-car driver" not "a racing-car driver".  *Tickle-monster* is your imaginary creature. It would be understood to mean a monster who tickles, as would "the tickling monster".

Comment: @TRomano: why did you use in your answer "tickle machine", but "sewing machine"? I still feel lost.

Comment: @Honza Zidek: probably by analogy with "massage chair".